# how do I display file permissions of rpm internal contents

Tags: rpm

I want to see what permissions the files within an rpm will "have" after the rpm is installed.  But without having to install the rpm.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `--dump` option to `rpm` gives you this information (as well as other information).

```
rpm -qp --dump "$RPM_PACKAGE_FILENAME"
```

Comment: Interesting. `rpm --dump -qp packagename.noarch.rpm` gives me lines like `/home/.../filename 694 1440086385 cdc64eac59d2d1400cabb433e1cd11af 0100750 USER USER 0 0 0 X` perhaps one of those is permissions do you think?

Comment: Yes, the `0100750` bit there. See the man page for the `--dump` option for what all the fields are.

Answer (score 11):

On CentOS 6 and 7, adding the `-l` and `-v` options to `-qp` seems to be enough:

```
$ rpm -qpl golang-vet-0-1.0.hgd32b5854c941.el7.x86_64.rpm
/usr/bin/vet
/usr/lib/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/vet
$ rpm -qplv golang-vet-0-1.0.hgd32b5854c941.el7.x86_64.rpm
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root    root                  5764251 Aug 21  2014 /usr/bin/vet
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root    root                       12 Aug 21  2014 /usr/lib/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/vet -> /usr/bin/vet
$ rpm --version
RPM version 4.11.3
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way that shows you permissions "like `ls` does":

```
 $ rpm -q --qf "[%-15{=NAME} %-36{FILENAMES} %{FILEMODES:perms}\n]" -p $FILENAME
 FILENAME            /etc/pam.d/sudo                      -rw-r--r--
 FILENAME            /etc/file/name/here                  -rw-r--r--
 ....
```

[ref](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/RPM-Guide-Using_RPM_DB-Querying_file_information.html)

Answer (score 2):

I just use `less`. ;) It shows the permissions in `ls`-style form.

In RedHat-based distros, it seems to pass it to `rpm -qpivl --changelog` (via `/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh`)

Comment: example please?

Comment: @rogerdpack `less your_rpm_here.rpm`?

Comment: Mine just has some weird control character codes if I do that... :|

Comment: Then I guess you don't have the `lesspipe`; you can use the `rpm` command shown.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This is the same solution than provided by muru (Just confirming it also works on MacOS `brew install rpm`)

Also works on MacOS (rpm installed via brew)

```
$ rpm --version
RPM version 4.14.0

$ rpm -qvlp <rpm-packagename>
```